# How do the 'new' keyword work ? I just recently learned about the new keyword

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string>* Boom = new vector<string>(90);
    Boom->push_back("Boom, son");
    cout << Boom->capacity();

    return 0;
}
```

I just recently learned about the new keyword and at the same time I'm learning about vectors so I decided to combine the two.

As far as I know, the 'new' keyword is supposed to set aside some memory on the heap.

Now, according to the above code, I have some questions:

Does the 90 in the brackets say how much memory to set aside in bytes or does it do something else?

Strings have a size of 28, so why when I run the code I get a value of 135? I expected to still get 90 because I've set aside 90 bytes and the string (being the only element in the vector) is only 28 bytes.

Am I thinking all wrong about this or am I thinking straight but I'm doing it wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Size is how many elements are in the vector. Capacity is how many elements that could fit in it without having to reallocate the memory. 90 is indeed the size of the vector, not in bytes, but in number of elements.

Comment: You will almost never have to (or even want to) dynamically allocate a vector.

Comment: You initialized your vector to hold 90 strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the 90 in the brackets say how much memory to set aside in bytes or does it do something else?

In the statement:

```
vector<string>* Boom = new vector<string>(90);
```

The `90` in parentheses has nothing to do with the `new` keyword, it is simply an argument to the `vector<string>` constructor (constructor (3) at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

> > 3) Constructs the container with count default-inserted instances of T.

You have simply dynamically allocated a *single* vector and inserted 90 `string` objects.

> Strings have a size of 28, so why when I run the code I get a value of 135? I expected to still get 90 because I've set aside 90 bytes and the string (being the only element in the vector) is only 28 bytes.

The static sizeof a `std::string` object is implementation dependent - in my test at https://www.onlinegdb.com/ it was only 8.  You did not allocate 90 bytes you allocated the static size of a single vector (24 at onlineGDB). The space for the 90 elements inserted are independently dynamically allocated by the vector class itself (i.e. internally `std::vector` invokes `new` to allocate space.

Moreover `capacity()` returns the number of objects that may be added to the vector before it must internally reallocate space.   The actual number of objects in the vector is returned by `length()`.  The capacity is normally higher than the length because the `vector` template over-allocates to avoid the need for frequent reallocation/copy.  It is a requirement of a `vector` that all elements are adjacent and ordered in memory, so if you insert a new object and the capacity is exceeded, the vector has to reallocate and move all the existing elements to the new memory space.

Dynamically allocating the vector itself is of limited benefit since the actual objects in the vector are themselves dynamically allocated.

> As far as I know, the 'new' keyword is supposed to set aside some memory on the heap.

Not only that - that is what `malloc()` does.  `new` dynamically instantiates *objects*.  That means that not only is the space for the object allocated, but also the constructor called.

so:

```
new T ;     // allocates a `T` object and calls its default constructor.

new T(a) ;  // allocates a `T` object and passes argument `a` 
            //  to a constructor taking arg of `a`'s type.

new T[n] ;  // allocates n x `T` objects and calls the default 
            // constructor of each.

new T(a)[n] ;  // allocates n x `T` objects and passes `a` to 
               // each constructor.
```

Answer (score 3):

In the expression `new T(param)`, `new` will allocate enough memory to store the *type* of object being constructed (`T`), in this case a `vector<string>`. The parenthesis are for parameters passed to the constructor, so it will construct the object via `vector<string>(90)` (which means to create a vector with 90 strings).

You may be confused because `vector` will allocate its own memory to hold the elements separate from the vector object itself. So `new` is only allocating `sizeof(vector<string>)` bytes and the construction of the vector will allocate another `90 * sizeof(string)` bytes, *roughly*.

Comment: `vector` will _over-allocate_ to reduce reallocate-and-move when new elements are added because all elements in a vector must be contiguous and ordered in memory.  In this case it has allocated capacity for 135 strings.  In my test it allocated 180.  The `count` argument refers to the number of default-constructed strings _inserted_ on construction of the vector.

Comment: @Clifford You're absolutely right, I had added the "*roughly*" for covering situations like that, since the standard is a lenient both for allocation strategies and vector's capacity logic. I just forgot to address the 135 part of question.

Answer (score 0):

`new` is an operator and it will allocate memory for an object (`new`) or array of objects (`new[]`) of type-name from the free store and returns a suitably typed, nonzero pointer to the object.

In your example it will allocate memory for `vector<string>(90)` and it will return pointer on that piece of memory.